# java regular expression matches first 6 digits in a list

Tags: java, regex

I have a range of numbers separated by comma, which is stored in a csv file. I am trying to match first 6 digits, for example: "130001X, XYZ" can be considered a group of digits in which X can be anything (0-9).

Is it possible? Can I use Java regular expression to match these and group them to a list?

Thanks!

1300010,10 1300011,10 1300012,22 1300013,22 1300014,22 1300015,533 1300016,535 1300017,531 1300018,22 1300019,22

1300050,20 1300051,20 1300052,20 1300053,20 1300054,20 1300055,20 1300056,20 1300057,20 1300058,20 1300059,20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hL6fE7/1)

Assuming that X is the same in `X,X` and `YZ` are also two random digits

```
\b130001(\d),\1\d{2}\b
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question. But if you want to match the numbers having 13000x,xxx then you can use a regex like this:

```
\b130001\d,\d{3}\b
```